# ImageMagick make can't build ghostscript

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, osx-server

I have installed Ghostscript successfully on my server and when I run the ./configure for ImageMagick it recognizes Ghostscript, but the --with-gslib can't be found. When I run:

./configure --with-gslib=yes

I get the following:

```
Delegate Configuration:
BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes      yes
Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no       no
Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=default    none
DJVU              --with-djvu=yes       no
DPS               --with-dps=yes        no
FFTW              --with-fftw=yes       no
FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes        no
FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes     no
FreeType          --with-freetype=yes       no
GhostPCL          None              pcl6 (unknown)
GhostXPS          None              gxps (unknown)
Ghostscript       None              gs (9.05)
Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=default    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/
Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=yes      no
Graphviz          --with-gvc=no     
JBIG              --with-jbig=yes       no
JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes       yes
JPEG-2000         --with-jp2=yes        no
LCMS v1           --with-lcms=yes       no
LCMS v2           --with-lcms2=yes      no
LQR               --with-lqr=yes        no
LTDL              --with-ltdl=yes       no
LZMA              --with-lzma=yes       yes
Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes   yes
OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes        no
PANGO             --with-pango=yes      no
PERL              --with-perl=no        no
PNG               --with-png=yes        yes
RSVG              --with-rsvg=no        no
TIFF              --with-tiff=yes       yes
WEBP              --with-webp=no        no
Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=  none
WMF               --with-wmf=no     no
X11               --with-x=         yes
XML               --with-xml=yes        yes
ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes       yes
```

As you can see Gslib keeps returning no... it's becoming really frustrating and I was wondering if anyone knows the answer for this?

Cheers,

Hide

Comment: I actually got the same problem right now with ImageMagick 6.8.6 and ghostscript 9.10.  Did you have any luck?